# Rails] Rich text editor uploading to Amazon S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, ckeditor, carrierwave, redactor

I would like to use either ckeditor or redactor for my rails application.
Both [ckeditor](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor) and [redactor-rails](https://github.com/SammyLin/redactor-rails) have nice integration with Carrierwave already, but I'd like to know how to edit the upload folder to my Amazon S3 instead of the default folder inside the application.

Redactor javascript version ([this](http://imperavi.com/redactor/examples/s3/)) actually provides a way to do this with javascript, but I would like to do it through my rails app using Carrierwave and Fog. That seems more natural to me but please tell me if there is no harm of doing it with javascript or benefit doing it with Carrierwave and Fog.

Since I haven't found a solution to this problem yet, I've avoided from integrating a rich text editor, and made users just use plain text and upload one picture  per post. However, a nice text editor has become a necessity now.

I couldn't find any documentation on this matter, and I'm sure there are many others who have faced a similar problem.

If anyone knows how to fix the settings of ckeditor and redactor to upload pictures to Amazon S3 using carrierwave and fog, please leave an answer. It will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you should consider changing your `carrierwave` config for uploading to S3 . Just have to make clear what is the name of the uploader that is used by `redactor-rails` gem .

Answer (score 3):

There is no harm in putting the configuration in the javascript side since your private key is never exposed (And you should never expose it).

You generate the signature and policy using the following code (which is on the server).

```
policy_json='{"expiration": "2020-01-01T00:00:00Z",

  "conditions": [ 
    {"bucket": "bucket name"}, 
    ["starts-with", "$key", ""],
    {"acl": "public-read"},
    {"success_action_redirect": "redirect url"},
    ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", ""],
    ["content-length-range", 0, 1048576]
  ]
}'
policy=Base64.encode64(policy_json).gsub("\n","")
signature = Base64.encode64(OpenSSL::HMAC.digest(OpenSSL::Digest::Digest.new('sha1'), 'Your private key', policy)).gsub("\n","")
```

So your private key is stored on the server side and now you can make a ajax call to get these values (policy and signature) and put it on your view.

Now in your bucket policy you can specify that AllowedOrigin is www.yourwebsite.com.

What this will do is it will allow only your website to post content to the bucket hence prevent any malicious user from posting stuff to your account.